# Resourses missing on old android smartphones after some time after start

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have created simple LibGDX game and everything works fine on LG L90 (5.0), Sony Xperia Z1 (4.4) and some other smartphones, but when I run my game om HTC WildFire S (2.3.5) after some interactions with game screens (every time it happens in different places of game) some pictures do not draw, and when I go to screen which would be created again game crashes. LogCat message:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
>       at
>   android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1080)
>       at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1038)
>       at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1364)
>       at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)

I use AssetManager to load resources. Although I create some pixmaps in my game, not from a file, which miss too. I don't know what to do. I think that may be Garbage Collector collects resources that are still in use because of memory loss, but in Android Studio I see that my game uses only 5-8 Mb memory. It is a really simple game and I don't want to limit its usage to only newer smartphones.

This is a class where I create some pixmaps:

```
public Preview(final int stageNumber, int width, int height) {
        this.stageNumber = stageNumber;

        stages = new Stages(stageNumber);

        /** Draw cell */
        cellWidth = width / stages.template[0].length;
        cellHeight = height / stages.template.length;
        Pixmap cellPixmap = new Pixmap(cellWidth, cellHeight, Format.RGB888);
        cellPixmap.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        cellPixmap.fill();
        cellPixmap.setColor(Color.valueOf("7d7d7d"));
        cellPixmap.drawLine(0, 0, cellPixmap.getWidth(), 0);
        cellPixmap.drawLine(cellPixmap.getWidth(), 0, cellPixmap.getWidth(), cellPixmap.getHeight());
        cellPixmap.drawLine(cellPixmap.getWidth(), cellPixmap.getHeight(), 0, cellPixmap.getHeight());
        cellPixmap.drawLine(0, cellPixmap.getHeight(), 0, 0);
        if ((Gdx.graphics.getPpiX() > 300) && (stages.template[0].length < 13)) {
            cellPixmap.drawLine(1, 1, cellPixmap.getWidth() - 1, 1);
            cellPixmap.drawLine(cellPixmap.getWidth() - 1, 1, cellPixmap.getWidth() - 1, cellPixmap.getHeight() - 1);
            cellPixmap.drawLine(cellPixmap.getWidth() - 1, cellPixmap.getHeight() - 1, 1, cellPixmap.getHeight() - 1);
            cellPixmap.drawLine(1, cellPixmap.getHeight() - 1, 1, 1);
        }
        cellQuad = new Texture(cellPixmap);

        setWidth(cellWidth * stages.template[0].length);
        setHeight(cellHeight * stages.template.length);
        addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                /** Some code */
            }
        });

        Pixmap grayPxmp = new Pixmap((int) getWidth(), (int) getHeight(), Format.RGB888);
        grayPxmp.setColor(Color.valueOf("cecece"));
        grayPxmp.fill();
        grayQuad = new Texture(grayPxmp);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        if (stageChoosed == stageNumber) {
            batch.draw(grayQuad, getX() - 5, getY() - 5, getWidth() + 10, getHeight() + 10);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < stages.template.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < stages.template[0].length; j++)
                if (stages.template[i][j] != -1)
                    batch.draw(cellQuad, getX() + j * cellWidth,
                            getY() + i * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight);
    }
}
```

And this is how I use this class.

```
    levelsTable = new Table();
    for (int i = 0; i < Stages.count; i++) {
        levelsTable.add(new Preview(i, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 3, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 3))
                .pad(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 15);
        if (i % 2 == 1)
            levelsTable.row();
    }
    stage.addActor(levelsTable);
```

Comment: Do you dispose any asset which is loaded with AssetManager?

Comment: No I do not. I do not dispose anything.

Comment: Do you have methods to handle pause and resume which are onPause and onResume in AndroidLauncher class?

Comment: I have only super.onResume() and super.onPause() there.

Comment: That's ok. They are needed for handling resume and pause situations. And for your question GLSurfaceView onPause and onResume which I thought causing your error, but they are not. Do you load & dispose your created pixmaps properly? Can you isolate them to see if they are causing. And is there any of them static?

Comment: None of them are static and do not dispose those textures/pixmaps at all and I think that I load them properly. Do you think that proper disposing could help?

Comment: could you please just share a part of your code? For example the game Screen class

Comment: I added example to the question.

Comment: Not disposing of them could be the problem...by loading the screen multiple times you are loading many textures and might be hitting a limit.

Comment: Well, I have only one example of every texture stored in Asset Manager. I just have multiple links to them it can't be a problem as I think. I dispose them only on game exit. As for pixmaps which I make in-app, I make them only once and I don't dispose the screen they show on.

Comment: No, your textures stored in AssetManager won't be a problem. But as I said before everything you create without using AssetManager needs proper disposing. So for your situation you should consider disposing pixmaps and screens when you don't use anymore. When you use that screen again, you can create screen and pixmaps again.